# Controllers of custom module not working in Odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, controllers, openerp-8, odoo-9

I am new to Odoo 9 (and openerp in general) and I am trying to follow the website builder tutorial [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/howtos/website.html) but I still can't figure out why my controller is not working : 
I get the '404 Page not found' error everytime I go to the indicated route even though I followed the exact same steps.

Can anybody help me out with that?

Thanks!

Comment: even though you followed the exact same steps can you post the code of your controller?

Comment: share some code you have tried

Comment: @Hatim if you have more than one database than delete all other databases and try it will work.